# Flutter DropdownMenuItem delete

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm developing a combobox using Flutter. combobox needs to be this month and next months. should write month name in combobox and return the number of the selected month. How can I do this in the shortest way?
I developed 12 months as DropdownMenuItem. I gave the current month as the default value. So far everything is fine. but how can I make the items of the past months invisible?

Comment: Hello, Can you provide some code snippets?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MonthPicker-class.html you can try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code for a similar problem.
This solution includes [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package but you can change the code in list generation for your purpose.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(){
  var today = DateTime.now();
  
  var length = 12 - today.month + 1;  // I added +1 because I want to include current month too
  
  List validMonths = List.generate(length,(index){
    return DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime(0, (today.month + index)));
  });
  
  print(validMonths);
}
```